# PHP: Image Check Extension

Tags: php, image

I am currently having some problems with my upload script.
It does not check if the filetype is allowed or not, and i can't figure out why.
Does anyone see my problem?

```
                //Reads the image name
            $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

            //If empty
            if ($image == "") {
            echo '<div class="box_square form_error" style="margin-bottom:15px; padding:10px; font-size:11px;">Velg et bilde!</div>';
            $errors = 1;
            }   

            //If not empty
            if ($image)
            {
                //Get orgiginal name from client machine
                $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                //Get the extension
                $extension = getExtension($filename);
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                //If file extension not known, error. If not, continue
                if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg"))
                {
                    //Error message
                    echo '<div class="box_square form_error" style="margin-bottom:15px; padding:10px; font-size:11px;">Bare JPG og JPEG er tilatte filtyper!</div>';
                    $errors = 1;

                }
```

Comment: What happens that you don't want to happen?

Comment: It does not echo out the message when the filetype is not known.

Comment: Well, what does `$extension ` contain?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($extension);` right before checking it against valid extensions and look what's in there.

Comment: And what happens if I write a destructive PHP script and rename it to 'picture.jpg'? That's not the proper way to determine the file type. You should look into `mime_content_type()`, the Fileinfo extension and `$_FILES['name']['type']`. Btw, are you sure that it's not a problem in the form itself?

Comment: Can you post your code for `getExtension`?

Comment: What does `getExtension` do? Does it do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an incorrect getExtension($filename).   However, i don't know why you are using stripslashes.

How about

```
echo "the extension used is ".$extension."<br>";
```

after

```
$extension = strtolower($extension);
```

btw, you can extract the extension using expression regular

```
preg_match("/\.([^\.]+)$/", $filename, $extension);
```

Comment: That did not output anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT rely on the extension but on the [mime type](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) instead.

Comment: You would better check the mime type on the server as well and not believe what the browser sends you. Checking for file extensions, however, does not help. Your server might parse a lot of file extensions (e.g. php, phtml, php3, php4, php5, py, ...) somehow.

Comment: If they upload i got a script in the top of the code that checks the image content for tags and other stuff. If it has the tags or the other stuff the ip-adress is stored in a database that i call to block out the users trying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're counting on the user uploading a file with the proper extension.
An alternative is getimagesize() it will also tell you the Mime type.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

```
list ( $width, $height, $type, $html_dim ) = getimagesize ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
echo "\$type:" . var_dump($type);
```

I also see exif-imagetype() says it will do that too (but I've never used it).
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php